# Occasionally, Vaadin does not invalidate session after "Session timeout" message

Tags: java, session, vaadin, session-timeout

In my Vaadin application I have an issue when Vaadin does not invalidate session after "Session timeout" message. After getting this message users sometimes are able to click the link or refresh the page and continue working as if they are still being logged in.
I use the following parameters:

```
closeIdleSessions=true
heartbeatInterval=60
session-timeout=15
```

Last parameter (session-timeout) is also set in context.xml (session-timeout=900) and web.xml (session-config/session-timeout=15) as I didn't get clear from vaadin documentation, is there such a parameter for vaadin servlet or not.

Did anybody face the titular problem?

**UPDATE 1**: Fixed parameters snippet.

**UPDATE 2**: `SessionDestroyListener.sessionDestroy` does not get triggered when `Session expired` message appears.

**UPDATE 3**: Previous error appeared because of code mistake. Now `SessionDestroyListener.sessionDestroy` gets called, but I have no access to `HttpSession` from given event.

Here is my `SessionDestroyListener` code (please note the comment in one of `if` branches):

```
private static class SynchronizerSessionDestroyListener implements SessionDestroyListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroy(SessionDestroyEvent event) {
        if (event.getSession() != null){
            WrappedSession wrappedSession = event.getSession().getSession();
            if (wrappedSession instanceof WrappedHttpSession){
                WrappedHttpSession wrappedHttpSession = (WrappedHttpSession) wrappedSession;
                HttpSession httpSession = wrappedHttpSession.getHttpSession();
                if (httpSession != null){
                    try {
                        httpSession.invalidate();
                        logger.debug("Session '{}' was invalidated", httpSession.getId());
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
                        // do nothing, already invalidated
                        logger.debug("Session '{}' was already invalidated: {}", httpSession.getId(), e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Could not invalidate http session for vaadin session: http session is null"); // THIS IS THE BRANCH WHICH IS ACTUALLY GET EXECUTED ON 'SESSION EXPIRED' MESSAGE: event.getSession().getSession() is null!
                }
            } else {
                logger.warn("Could not invalidate http session for vaadin session: event session is not an http session");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Could not invalidate http session for vaadin session: event session is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I attach the listener:

```
public class X extends VaadinServlet {
    // different class members
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionDestroyListener(new SynchronizerSessionDestroyListener());
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post what your `web.xml` exactly looks like regarding those parameters? Or do you use the parameters using an annotation?

Answer (score 11):

I will try to explain how the session invalidation basically works, maybe this helps (I can't read too much information out of your question):

- Usually the session will timeout after the specified time inside the
  `session-timeout` parameter.
- **BUT** you have the take the **heartbeat
  interval** into account.    If your heartbeat interval is shorter
  than the session timeout (it usually is), the heartbeat will keep the session alive
  forever.
- Thats where the parameter `closeIdleSessions` is relevant. Setting
  this parameter to `true` the browser will not take the heartbeats as
  a valid request for the timeout, but the **last, non-heartbeat
  request**.
- **Second BUT:** When will the timeout be recognized? The client-side engine can only recognize this at a heartbeat or if the user takes some action (as in both cases a request to the server is done). By consequence the actual timeout will not occur when the specified timeout has passed, but at the **next heartbeat after the timeout**.
- Other situation: after 3 missing heartbeats, the server also closes the session. E.g. if the browser is closed this will cause the session to be invalidated as no heartbeats are sent.

Sample `web.xml` to explain better:

```
<context-param>
 <!-- ATTENTION: This value is set in SECONDS -->
 <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
 <param-value>180</param-value>
</context-param>

<session-config>
  <!-- ATTENTION: This value is set in MINUTES -->
  <session-timeout>4</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Using the above web.xml the session will timeout after 6 minutes (without user interaction).

**Explanation:**
the session timeout is set to 4 minutes, but there is no heartbeat at 4 minutes. The next heartbeat will be at 6 minutes. Now the client side engine knows that the session actually timed out and will show the according message.

*I am not sure if this is the same process when using Vaadin Push as there we have a continous channel from client to server.*

**Sources:**
[Book of Vaadin - 4.8.7. Session Expiration](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.session-expiration)
[Book of Vaadin - 4.9.6. Other Servlet Configuration Parameters, Session Timeout After User Inactivity](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html#application.environment.parameters)

**Additional information:**
Upcoming Vaadin 7.6 seems to improve client-server connection stability: [Blog Post](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-6-preview-improved-communication-mechanism)

Comment: As I said, this is just an explanation on how the session mechanism works as I couldnt reproduce your exact issue. Is it maybe possible that your heartbeat interval is set too low?

Comment: Sorry, I had a incorrectly quoted parameters, please see an updated version. Heartbeat interval is set to 1 minute. As I understand, JEE session expires on 3 heartbeats later than Vaadin's one. Is there any way in Vaadin to listen for it's own session expiration message, so I could do jeeSession.invalidate()?

Comment: Yes this is possible. See here: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.session

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that part of documentation )

Comment: Unfortunately, SessionDestroyListender does not get triggered when "Session expired" message appears.

Comment: Could you tell if you have enabled push-mode (and if yes, try without having it enabled to narrow the Problem) and provide the snippet where you add the SessionDestroyListener? Is it triggered when you manually close the session?

Comment: I've found a mistake in code - I do not add service.addSessionDestroyListener. I'll tell you more in a few hours.

Comment: btw, I do not use push service. The code snippet that I use now executes NPE-and-type-aware  version of code: sessionDestroyEvent.getSession().getSession().getHttpSession().invalidate()

Comment: please see update 3 in the question body: I'm still not able to call session.invalidate(), and after hitting F5 on the titular message I'm able to enter the same session again, and that sucks.

Comment: I am slowly running out of ideas unfortunately. Does the new session have the same session id? Would it be possible that you additionally post your question to the vaadin forums?

Comment: Right now this issue's priority is lowered in our project, so I will continue to investigate once it is raised again. Thank you for your participation though!