# Is there a lower bound of 15 mins for the Tomcat <session-timeout> value?

Tags: session, tomcat, timeout, config, web.xml

Is there a lower bound for the Tomcat server configuration property `<session-timeout>` ? Because, if I set it to 5 minutes the sessions always expires after 15 minutes. I also tried 1 minute and it was the same.

This is my `web.xml` for my webapp deployed under tomcat:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
           <http-only>true</http-only>
           <secure>false</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

I didn't find anything on the documentation, e.g.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017275

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no lower bound on this value. On a "hello world" web application deployed to Tomcat, you can observe that expiration works properly by looking at how often the `JSESSIONID` cookie value is refreshed in the browser.

If you set `session-timeout` to 1 minute and refresh the page after 1 minute, the value of `JSESSIONID` will be different. If you refresh it before 1 minute runs out, it will be the same. This proves that session expiration works as expected.

If in your case it's limited by 15 minutes, it might mean that your application itself does some additional session management.

The HTTP session is just a way to correlate the subsequent HTTP queries. By itself it has nothing to do with authentication or user being logged in / logged out. In case of Tomcat, the `session-config` configuration is related to the HTTP session management defined by the Servlet specification and supported by Tomcat as the servlet container.

The security framework that you use may take advantage of this Servlet HTTP session to attach authenticated user data, or it may create its own session for that. So expiration of Servlet HTTP session may not coincide with expiration of user login.

Comment: I got your point @Sergei, thanks for your prompt response. I can see the `JSESSIONID` cookie is renewed after 5 mins, but what I am asking for is: Why the "session" is not killed/invalidated till 15 mins pass. Probably this is not at all about **session expiration**, but rather **session handling** ?

Comment: JSESSIONID is by definition the identifier of a session, so a new identifier means the old session was invalidated and a new one was created. How exactly do you determine that the session was not invalidated?

Comment: Basically, I do expect (but I'm probably wrong) the "session expired - logout banner" to appear after that a period of inactivity - longer than the `<session-timeout>` value - is elapsed.

Comment: By “logout banner” I assume you use some kind of authentication framework? Do you use standard JavaEE security, Spring Security, something else? Different security frameworks may manage authentication in a different way, it may be flexibly configurable, and they also could have sessions independent from the one created by Tomcat.

Comment: Spring Security! But also Vaadin: indeed, this bit of information (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541628/6466510) should help. However, I still don't get the difference between: the session **expires** and the `JSESSIONID` is renewed, the user is **logged out** by the security framework and finally, a certain time passed from the last heartbeat/non-heartbeat request.

Comment: I've edited my answer and tried to explain a bit more about the difference.